# How to convert LinkedHashSet to two-dimensional array

Tags: java

I want to convert a LinkedHashSet into 2D Integer array.

`LinkedHashSet` is constructed from already available 2D Integer `array[n][3]` using `Set` and  `Arrays.asList()`, removed duplicates.

Now, if e.g. `[ [10, 14, -99], [10, 99, -14], [14, 99, -10] [null] ]` is a LinkedHashSet

I want

```
first[n][2]={ {10, 14}, {10, 99}, {14, 99}}
```

or

```
second[n][1]={ {-99}, {-14}, {-10} }
```

i.e. break `LinkedHashSet` (in which every node contains 3 integers as info field) into  two integer array  of size `[n][2]` and `[n][1]` as explained in above example.

I want an efficient and simple way to do this in java.

Comment: What have [you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)?

Comment: The only real way to do this is the "dumb" way of just looping through the `LinkedHashSet` and working with the arrays directly.

Answer (score 0):

I don;t think that java has any inbuilt method to convert a HashSet into 2D array. So as far as I know you will have to do it through iterating HashSet.

Answer (score 0):

I have been resolved the problem myself, the code is as below.

```
Let us given LinkedHashSet as Set<Set<Integer>> r the format is as given above;
```

First convert 2D array ar of size [r.size][3]; Then following code is implemented

```
int i=0;
for(Set<Integer> set:r)
ar[i++] = s.toArray(new Integer[3])



 Then store this ar[n][3] value into two separate array First[n][2] and Second[n][2] using looping.
```

Answer (score -1):

[image: convert]

Only way I can think of for this is
using temporary string variable to store the printed set, remove [ , ]
and then store that to the array, which is considered as inefficient, but working.